# Discord.py echo command

Tags: discord.py

So I am trying to make a discord.py echo/say command, but no response or errors are happening, if you know how to fix this please help me out!

```py
import discord, os, keep_alive, asyncio, datetime, pytz, requests

from discord.ext import tasks, commands

client = commands.Bot(
  command_prefix=':',
  self_bot=True
)

async def on_ready():
    client.remove_command('help')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("TEST"))



@client.command()
async def echo(ctx, *,args):
    if ctx.message.author.id in [782258096210051102]:
        await ctx.send(args)
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Bot developers only :<")

keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"), bot=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the `ctx.author` is `None`, to fix that enable `intents.members`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)

Answer (score 0):

Uhhhhhh it is better to do something like

```
@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx,*,arg):
            #the star is required
             if ctx.authir.id==782258096210051102:
                       await ctx.send(arg)
             else:
                       await ctx.send("devs only :<")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `' '.join(ctx.message.content.split()[1:])` to join all words after the first space. So something like:

```py
@client.command()
async def echo(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.send(' '.join(ctx.message.content.split()[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

To See Where The Problem Is From First Try:

```python
@client.command()
async def echo(ctx, *,args):
   await ctx.send(args[0])
   await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so actually you have need to do this:

```
@client.command(name='echo')
async def echo(ctx, *, what_bot_need_to_say: str):

    if ctx.message.author.id == 782258096210051102:
       await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1) # This delete an message in the channel
       await ctx.send(what_bot_need_to_say) # This the echo
    else:
       await ctx.send("Bot developers only :<")
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain more details, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, msg):
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy me it is the simplest and gives the correct format

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('?')

@bot.command()
async def repeat(ctx,*,repeat:str):

  if ctx.author.id == 782258096210051102:
    await ctx.send(f"{repeat}")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    return

  else:
    await ctx.send("Only devs")
    return


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("bot online")

bot.run("YOUR_TOKEN_HERE")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```py
import discord, os, keep_alive, asyncio, datetime, pytz, requests

from discord.ext import tasks, commands

client = commands.Bot(
  command_prefix=':',
  self_bot=True
)

async def on_ready():
    client.remove_command('help')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("TEST"))



@client.command()
async def echo(ctx, *,args):
    if ctx.author.id in [782258096210051102]:
        await ctx.send(args)
        # await ctx.message.delete() # i am not sure of delete you can add it if you want
    else:
        await ctx.send("Bot developers only :<")

keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"), bot=False)
```